# Problems with importing libraries to Cloud Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, langchain

I am trying to build some cloud functions and I am getting the same error over and over again. The code I am pasting here is just a code to test whether the error happens again. USING PYTHON 3.10

Cloud function main.py:

```
import functions_framework
import re
import os
import json
from io import BytesIO
from typing import Any, Dict, List, Optional, Awaitable, Callable, Tuple, Type, Union
from collections import OrderedDict
import base64
from langchain.llms import VertexAI
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.embeddings import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.docstore.document import Document
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.schema import BaseOutputParser, OutputParserException
from langchain.vectorstores import VectorStore
from langchain.vectorstores.faiss import FAISS
from langchain.chains import LLMChain
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
from langchain.chains.question_answering import load_qa_chain
from langchain.chains.qa_with_sources import load_qa_with_sources_chain
from langchain.chains import ConversationalRetrievalChain
from langchain.chains.conversational_retrieval.prompts import CONDENSE_QUESTION_PROMPT
from langchain.tools import BaseTool
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.docstore.document import Document
from pypdf import PdfReader
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL
from langchain.sql_database import SQLDatabase
from langchain.agents import AgentExecutor, initialize_agent, AgentType
from langchain.tools import BaseTool
from langchain.utilities import BingSearchAPIWrapper
from langchain.agents import create_sql_agent
from langchain.agents.agent_toolkits import SQLDatabaseToolkit
from pydantic import BaseModel
from langchain_experimental.sql import SQLDatabaseChain
from langchain.sql_database import SQLDatabase
from langchain.agents import AgentExecutor, initialize_agent, AgentType
from langchain.tools import BaseTool
from langchain.utilities import BingSearchAPIWrapper
from langchain.agents import create_sql_agent
from tools import SQLDbTool, ChatGPTTool, DocSearchTool, run_agent
from langchain.embeddings import VertexAIEmbeddings
from langchain.memory import ChatMessageHistory
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferWindowMemory
from langchain.agents import ConversationalChatAgent, AgentExecutor, Tool
from IPython.display import Markdown, HTML, display 
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.schema import *
from pybigquery.api import ApiClient
import pandas as pd


@functions_framework.http
def hello_http(request):
    """HTTP Cloud Function.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): The request object.
        <https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#incoming-request-data>
    Returns:
        The response text, or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using `make_response`
        <https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.make_response>.
    """
    request_json = request.get_json(silent=True)
    request_args = request.args

    if request_json and 'name' in request_json:
        name = request_json['name']
    elif request_args and 'name' in request_args:
        name = request_args['name']
    else:
        name = 'World'
    return 'Hello {}!'.format(name)
```

As you can see those are only imports and default code to send HTTP requests.

I also have requirements.txt file:

```
functions-framework==3.*
ipython==8.14.0
pybigquery==0.5.0
SQLAlchemy==1.4.49
pandas==2.0.3
pypdf==3.16.0
langchain==0.0.287
langchain-experimental==0.0.20
```

The error im getting while trying to test this function:

```
[builder] Running "python3 -m pip check"
[builder] No broken requirements found.
[builder] Done "python3 -m pip check" (2.249514671s)
[builder] === Utils - Label Image (google.utils.label@0.0.2) ===
ERROR: failed to build: executing lifecycle. This may be the result of using an untrusted builder: failed with status code: 62
[3:23:25 PM] - Error while building function sources. Please check logs.
```

Is there anyone that can help me with this issue? Thank you guys!

Comment: UPDATE: Whenever I put any additional requirements other than 'functions-framework', it crashes with the same error.

Comment: Some requirements require specific binaries to work among other things. Cloud functions not always will be able to fullfill this so it's possible that's the issue. You may want to use Cloud Run

Comment: @Puteri Thank you for the response. After hours of trying to fix this issue I just simply decided to try and deploy this function. Well... it deployed correctly and passed the tests. Seems like there are some issues when testing BEFORE deployment.

Answer (score 4):

Sharing this as a community wiki for the benefit of others

As mentioned by @Masiek

> @Puteri Thank you for the response. After hours of trying to fix this issue I just simply decided to try and deploy this function. Well... it deployed correctly and passed the tests. Seems like there are some issues when testing BEFORE deployment